# Puppet: load file content to variable (specifically hash variable)

Tags: puppet

I need to load the contents of some static files into some hash variables in Puppet in order to put them into a template. My folder layout is as follows:

```
./manifests/site.pp
./templates/script.sh.epp
./files/server1_part1.txt
       /server1_part2.txt
       /server2_part1.txt
       /server2_part2.txt
```

What I want to do now is to load the contents of the `./files/${hostname}${part}.txt` into the variables in a puppet hash in order to put them into the template. I know I could declare them in the `site.pp` but there are 10 machines all with different lines resulting in a manifest that would be unreadable.

Hash would look like this right now:

```
  $script_config_hashes = {
    part1 => "${source_path}/${hostname}_part1.txt",
    part2 => "${source_path}/${hostname}_part2.txt",
    part3 => "${source_path}/${hostname}_part3.txt",
  }
```

Any idea on how to achieve this? Reading the documentation didn't answer my question (or I overlooked the obvious). Puppet Master is Version 6.X

Answer (score 0):

You can load the contents of a file residing on the compile server via [the Puppet `file()` function](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.19/function.html#file).

However, based on the appearance of `manifests/site.pp`, I get the idea that you have in mind to put this in the root of your environment.  Don't.  Instead, create a module, and put the files, the template, and the manifest that consumes them into that module.  Aside from that being a widely accepted best practice, it will have the advantage of mooting the problem of constructing absolute paths to the wanted files.

With everything moved to module `mymodule`, the hash definition would look like this:

```
  $script_config_hashes = {
    part1 => file("mymodule/${hostname}_part1.txt"),
    part2 => file("mymodule/${hostname}_part2.txt"),
    part3 => file("mymodule/${hostname}_part3.txt"),
  }
```

Note in particular that no absolute path is required, and that the "files/" part of the paths is implicit.